# Hadoop Installation with Hostname Failed

Tags: hadoop, hostname, cloudera

i try to install hadoop single node,

when i try using localhost and my ip address on my configuration,my hadoop running well.
but when i change IP address to hostname, i got error.NameNode and JobTracker can't run.

What should i do ?

this is my config

```
1.core-site.xml

<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/tmp</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost</value>
</property>


2.hdfs-site.xml

<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value> //menujukkan jumlah cluster
</property>

3.mapred-site.xml

<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
<property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
    <value>/home/disk1/mapred/local</value>
</property>
```

This is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost cloudera_master
10.0.2.15  cloudera_master
```

I just change localhost to hostname "cloudera_master",but it's failed.
I have try add host to my /etc/hosts but it still failed

Help me please,

Comment: Can you post the actual errors from your NameNode and JobTracker logs.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem of  core-site.xml?  `<value> hdfs://localhost </value>`

Try this one. `<value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>`